# Web Scraping: innertext

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, getelementsbytagname

I would like an overview of real estate prices for a specific region.
I created code which transfers the prices into a list and makes a statistic.
My program scrapes the price, area and so on from a specific link.

In the next step I would like to create automatically this link-list by a VBA.
For this step I need to to extract the exposeIDs to Excel.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ExposeID()
Dim browser As Object   'Aufnehmen der verwendeten Instanz des Browsers (Internet Explorer)
Dim knotenAst As Object 'Aufnehmen einer HTML Struktur aus dem Browser Dokument
Dim url As String       'Aufnehmen der auszulesenden Adresse
Dim ExposeID As String

url = "https://www.examplexyz.de"
Set browser = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
browser.Visible = False
browser.navigate url
Do Until browser.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop

Set knotenAst = browser.document.getElementsByClassName("is24-res-list is24-res-gallery result-list border-top")(0).getElementsBytagName("li")

'ExposeID
 If Not knotenAst Is Nothing Then
 ExposeID = Trim(knotenAst.innerText)
    
 Else
 ExposeID = "KeinWert"
 End If
 MsgBox ExposeID, vbOKCancel

'Aufräumen
browser.Quit
Set browser = Nothing
Set knotenAst = Nothing

End Sub
```

**Expected Result:** A list of all exposeIDs.

**Actual Result:** I get a Dump.

Screenshot: HTML from the homepage (tag is yellow highlighted)
[image]

Picture of my list:
[![Result in Excel][2]][2]

Comment: knotenAst is a collection. It does not have an innerText property.

Comment: Do you really want _all_ the exposeIds?

Comment: @QHarr: Thanks for your answer. Yes, it´s important to get all expose-IDs. The [LINK](https://www.immobilienscout24.de/Suche/radius/haus-kaufen?centerofsearchaddress=Oldenburg%20(Kreis);;;;;Wildeshausen&geocoordinates=52.89467;8.43212;10.0&pagenumber=2) includes a list of houses for a special region. <br/> If I have the list of ExposeIDs, I can pick the requested information like price e.g. from the respective detail page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use a combination of class and attribute css selectors

```
Dim nodeList As Object, i As Long

Set nodeList = browser.document.querySelectorAll(".result-list__listing[data-id]")

For i = 0 To nodeList.Length - 1 

    Debug.Print nodeList.item(i).getAttribute("data-id")

Next
```

Comment: The `data-id` are available in page source but it seems xhr finds trouble fetching them.

Comment: Ah... I can no longer run vba. @SIM. Are the values actually present in response? I can retrieve with any parser in python but note there are a lot of errors in the html source. Some of which might throw off vba parser. Java + css gets thrown off. Also, should test user-agent.

Comment: I see only 18 of 20 ids when using regex (I know!!!) of _palm--shortlist-container.*?data-id="(\d+)"_ on java response where parser fails. Missing are '109663818', '117607563' but present are '109663818', '115530390', '116793645', '116969227', '77274945', '117746768', '117160707', '114991665', '114471256', '117607563', '117882741', '115027075', '115027063', '117879476', '117370369', '117013902', '116790376', '116763107', '113800677', '114320268'

Comment: I tried to find the ids within `http.responseText` but what I could see there instead are a lot of script tags and stuff, so I'm wondering how could you grab them using regex. You are talking about doing regex within vba, right?

Comment: I am using java as I can't run vba any more. With java same problem with parser falling over but there are ids within response.

Comment: It's weird cos you can see they are retrieved perfectly with python requests (of course that also adds default header)

Comment: It works! Iam really happy about your great support. Now I can proceed working on my sheet.

Comment: No worries :-)  Pleasure

Answer (score 0):

I know this is really, really primitive, compared to the stuff QHarr throws up here all the time, but it may be good enough for a start.

```
Sub DumpData()

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True

URL = "https://www.immobilienscout24.de/Suche/de/niedersachsen/oldenburg-oldenburg/haus-kaufen?pagenumber=1"

'Wait for site to fully load
IE.Navigate2 URL
Do While IE.Busy = True
   DoEvents
Loop

RowCount = 2

With Sheets("Sheet1")
   .Cells.ClearContents
   For Each itm In IE.document.all
      If itm.ID Like "*result-*" Then
        .Range("B" & RowCount) = itm.ID
        RowCount = RowCount + 1
      End If
   Next itm
End With
End Sub
```

Result:

[image]